# Pagination with rocksolid custom content elements

Tags: pagination, contao

I created a custom rocksolid content element. Now I would like to have pagination for that content element in the frontend. Is it possible to have pagination to be configured with rocksolid custom content element. If so, how it is possible? My config file is

```
'inputType' => 'list',
        'fields' => array(
            'html' => array(
                'label' => array(
                    'en' => array('Script code', ''),
                    'de' => array('Script code', ''),
                ),
                'inputType' => 'text',
                'eval' => array('mandatory'=>true, 'allowHtml'=>true, 'class'=>'monospace', 'rte'=>'ace|html', 'helpwizard'=>true),
            ),
            'text' => array(
                'label' => array(
                    'en' => array('Text', ''),
                    'de' => array('Text', ''),
                ),
                'inputType' => 'textarea',
                'eval' => array(
                    'rte' => 'tinyMCE',
                    'tl_class' => 'clr',
                ),
            ),
```

Is it possible to add the pagination configuration in this config file? If so what is the configuration?

Comment: What exactly do you need to be paginated?

Comment: In the frontend, I need to display only 5 items. Rest of them in second page. And also I need to have front and back buttons.

Comment: You need to implement that manually in your `rsce_….html5` template. The `Contao\Pagination` class can help with generating the pagination markup.

Comment: I added the following to .html5 file. But it is displaying only the pagination and there is no functionality. The code is <?php
$b = 3;
$objPagination = new \Pagination(4, $b, \Config::get('maxPaginationLinks'), 'page_n' . 380);
$this->Template->pagination = $objPagination->generate("\n  ");
?>........ And I called <?= $this->pagination ?> below it. Why it is not showing the functionality? Is this is not the correct method?

Comment: You need to program the functionality yourself. You need to filter your list array according to the pagination parameters.

Comment: From pagination.php core file, what I understood is, we just need to pass the parameters "$intRows, $intPerPage, $intNumberOfLinks=7, $strParameter='page', Template $objTemplate=null, $blnForceParam=false". Rest of the functionalities are implemented in this pagination.php file(vendor/contao/core-bundle/src/resources/contao/library/Contao). And we just need to call that pagination in our .html5 file.  I am not sure whether my thought is right or not?

Comment: The `Contao\Pagination` class only helps you with the generation of the pagination itself, i.e. the previous, next and pages links etc. It does not filter the actual data for you.